# Referencing generic class in XAML

Tags: xaml, namespaces

I have a class C which is derived from a generic class D. I referenced the class C in a XAML file. When I build the app, I get the following error:

*The tag 'C' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:A.B'*

I don't understand is this due to C is derived from a generic class. If I remove the base class, it does not give me any error.

How can I get rid of the error? The IInterfaceForE is injected via Unity, so the app works fine. But I can't get rid of the build error.

Code snippet:

```
namespace A.B
{
    public class C : D<InterfaceForE>
    {
        public C()
        {
        }
    }
}

// Reference in XAML

xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:A.B"

<myns:C x:Key="KeyForC"/>

// Code snippet after commenting out the base class. 
// When I build with this code, there is no build error, but the app wont run.

namespace A.B
{
    public class C //: D<InterfaceForE>
    {
        public C()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the generic being used to make this work.